# Why is this plane circling over and over so late at night

Tags: general-aviation

[image]

[Link to the specific flight on FlightRadar24](https://www.flightradar24.com/data/aircraft/g-hmgc#339cafec)

Why is this plane circling over and over so late?

Really interesting, love tracking planes

Answer (score 6):

Beech Super King Air G-HMGC was registered to [ACH London Ltd](https://planelogger.com/Aircraft/Registration/G-HMGC/1061397) in June 2022. [Website](https://suite.endole.co.uk/insight/company/10586808-ach-london-limited) is listed as 2excelengineering.com, which describes the company:

> 2Excel Engineering Ltd is an independent, UK-CAA, EASA, FAA and TCCA approved Maintenance and Repair Organisation (MRO) for Boeing, Airbus, Beechcraft and Piper aircraft. 2Excel Engineering’s breadth, scale and flexibility enables it to undertake programmed ‘nose-to-tail’ maintenance, modifications and unscheduled work.

There are, however, multiple companies associated with this holding company. Another is [2ExcelAviation](https://www.2excelaviation.com/capability-development/) which states that:

> It transforms small and large aircraft utility by designing, manufacturing, installing, testing and certifying modifications to the aircraft to make them useful to customers for their specific missions...(it) has certified a number of innovative approaches to create aircraft level installations ... King Air reconnaissance platforms.

The flight was likely testing some modification to the King Air. They seem to have a wide range of interest, but they specifically call out the recon platform for this aircraft. Circling would allow testing of observation equipment or the aircraft control needed by such equipment. They would test a new product in their own aircraft before offering or releasing it to customers.

Comment: Interestingly at least some of the tests seem to be done at very low altitude, that's what the yellow trail color means in Flightradar24. On a flight yesterday it took off from Humberside at 9:15 pm local time, climbed up to 17,000 feet and flew out over the middle of the English Channel, then descended to 800 ft and spent an hour an a half circling around above the water between 800 and 875 ft, then moved up to around 950 feet and circled for another half an hour, then headed back to Humberside where it arrived at 1:20 am local.

Comment: Ah thank you , I was watching it for a while and was interested what was happening.

Answer (score 3):

"SRD224" seems to be UK Coast Guard ID. https://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/srd224

Possibly training, or looking for someone.