# Unusual pattern over English Channel

Tags: military, navigation

I have just spotted this Beechcraft flying an unusual pattern over the English Channel (late at night). It has no call sign etc. I'm thinking maybe a military aircraft looking for illegal migrant boats with thermal imaging (altitude is a constant 1900ft). Any thoughts?

[image: flight radar screenshot]

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/102490) about the same aircraft SRD244B

Answer (score 9):

Note that the flight does not have "no callsign;" rather, the specific website/app you were using voluntarily chooses to not display the callsign. From [the ADS-B Exchange replay](https://globe.adsbexchange.com/?icao=407814&lat=51.119&lon=1.524&zoom=9.5&showTrace=2024-03-21), we can see that the [aircraft registration](https://www.caa.co.uk/aircraft-register/g-info/search-g-info/) is  `G-HMGA` and it was using the callsign `SRD244B`. "SRD" is the identifier for HM Coastguard and on the radio the callsign would sound like "COASTGUARD TWO TWO FOUR BRAVO."

[image: Screenshot of ADS-B Exchange replay at approximately 2024-03-21 0010Z showing an aircraft performing maneuvers over the Straits of Dover. The aircraft is a Super King Air (type code BE20) registered as G-HMGA and using the callsign SRD224B.]

According to Wikipedia, HM Coastguard does **not** perform the functions of "Customs/Border Control, Fisheries Control and Law Enforcement." This leads me to believe that the aircraft would not have been searching for migrant boats simply on general customs/border control principles; they could have been searching for a boat in distress, as "Search and Rescue" is one of the Coastguard's functions. Or it could be that Wikipedia is not correct, or it could be that the Coastguard does sometimes support other agencies' missions.

Of some passing interest, the registered owners of `G-HMGA` are not the Coastguard themselves but a private company called "ACH London Ltd." This seems to be a holding company associated with [2Excel Aviation](https://www.2excelaviation.com/). Apparently the Coastguard does not directly own and presumably does not directly maintain this aircraft, even though it is painted in Coastguard livery.

> [image: Photograph of a Super King Air 200 (registration G-HMGA) in HM Coastguard red-and-white livery. The aircraft is photographed from the starboard side as it flies left-to-right through the shot. The aircraft has just taken off from Aberdeen International (Dyce) Airport (EGPD) and the landing gear are just beginning to retract.]
> *Lloyd Bell at JetPhotos*

Comment: 2excel all but admit they do "law enforcement" and "surveillance" (read as: search for migrant boats) using these exact aircraft: https://www.2excelaviation.com/2excel-aviation-delivers-life-saving-surveillance-capability/ . In addition the area they were operating in is almost constantly NOTAM'd for this exact purpose.

Answer (score -1):

Could be any number of reasons. Polling ocean buoys, aircrew training, ship crew training, google map something or other.

Or, searching for a maritime craft, doing something it should not be doing in the English CHannel.

It took off from Humberside, and is presumably returning there.

[image]

Comment: RAF commander who doesn't know that [Operation Fortitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Fortitude) is over.

Comment: [HM Coastguard aircraft/flight.](https://globe.adsbexchange.com/?icao=407814&lat=51.119&lon=1.524&zoom=9.5&showTrace=2024-03-21) Wikipedia says that Customs/Border Control, Fisheries Control, and Law Enforcement are the three functions *not* carried out by the Coastguard, but I don't know if that means they never support the agencies who are responsible for those functions.

Comment: FYI: people are not "illegals", they are people.